# AngularJS, factory VisualForce Remoting error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, visualforce, angularjs-factory

So I was trying to create something that will dynamically pull data from SalesForce and display it in my angular App. I created the .factory function below:

```
app.factory('getDocuments', ['$q','$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope){
    return function (inputString) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            'FO_Manager.getDocuments', 
            inputString,
            function(result, event){
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                if(event.status) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(event);
                }
            })
        },
        {buffer: true, escape: true, timeout: 30000}
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}}]);
```

It runs great if I run it in the controller when the page loads `getDocuments('a0N17000001NxjO').then(function(result){$scope.documents = result;},
                            function(error){$scope.error = result;});`

The problem arises when I try to run it within my directive dynamically

```
app.directive('foSidenav',['getDocuments', function(getDocuments){
function linker($scope, element, attrs){
    $scope.selectDocType = function(id)
    {
        alert('docId updated');
        alert(id);
        getDocuments(id).then(function(result){$scope.DocType = result;},
            function(error){$scope.error = result;});
    };
}
return{

    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {

        info:'=',
        DocType:'='
    },
    templateUrl:function(element,attr){

        return  attr.url;
    },
    link:linker
};}]);
```

Now the problem is when I run this code the alert show fine but then I get this error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Any Idea how to get around this??

Comment: Does your `getDocuments(...)` call return any `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out the error was elsewhere, this particular error did not prevent the script from running appropriately.

Some of my syntax was off!